# Request using POST method returns a none value

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, apscheduler

I am trying to get APScheduler to return the list of jobs but it always returns a none value.

main.py:

```
def test():
    print("test")


app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler.add_job(func=test, trigger='cron', hour='11', minute= '36')
scheduler.start() 

@app.route('/viewjobs', methods=['POST'])
def view():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            
        string = str(scheduler.print_jobs())                   
        return(string)

if __name == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now when i send a POST request using curl i get None.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: consider use https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.get_jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.print_jobs), it clearly says that `print_jobs()` prints a formatted list of jobs to the standard output. The function call returns `None`. A quick fix would be to use a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object as the output sink and return its contents:

```
buffer = io.StringIO()
scheduler.print_jobs(out=buffer)
return buffer.getvalue()
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this in practice.